# Xacro include breaks including xacro file

Tags: ros, include, ros-kinetic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a xacro file named "diff_wheeled_robot.urdf.xacro" to describe a robot and it works just fine. It is including other xacro files and their xacro macros.
Now I want to include another xacro file describing a laser. The following code is the laser file ("rplidar.urdf.xacro"):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="rplidar" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:include filename="$(find testbot_description)/urdf/inertias.urdf.xacro" /> 
    <xacro:include filename="$(find testbot_description)/urdf/materials.urdf.xacro" /> 

    <xacro:property name="rplidar_mass" value="0.2" /> 
    <xacro:property name="rplidar_radius" value="0.0757" /> 
    <xacro:property name="rplidar_height" value="0.04080" />

    <xacro:macro name="rplidar" params="parent translateX translateY">
        <link name="rplidar_link">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <mass value="${rplidar_mass}"/>
                <cylinder_inertia m="${rplidar_mass}" r="${rplidar_radius}" h="${rplidar_height}"/>
            </inertial>
            <visual>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder length="${rplidar_height}" radius="${rplidar_radius}" />
                </geometry>
                <material name="Blue" />
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder length="${rplidar_height}" radius="${rplidar_radius}" />
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>

        <joint name="rplidar_joint" type="fixed">
            <parent link="${parent}"/>
            <child link="rplidar_link"/>
        </joint>
        
        <gazebo reference="rplidar_link">
            <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
            <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
            <sensor type="ray" name="rplidar_sensor">
                <pose>${rplidar_radius/2} 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                <visualize>true</visualize>
                <update_rate>10</update_rate>
                <ray>
                    <scan>
                        <horizontal>
                            <samples>8000</samples>
                            <min_angle>0</min_angle>
                            <max_angle>3.14159265359</max_angle>
                        </horizontal>
                    </scan>
                    <range>
                        <min>0.15</min>
                        <max>8.0</max>
                        <resolution>0.001</resolution>
                    </range>
                </ray>
                <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_rplidar_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
                    <topicName>/scan</topicName>
                    <frameName>rplidar_link</frameName>
                </plugin>
            </sensor>
        </gazebo>
    </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

But when I try to include it via

```
<xacro:include filename="${find testbot_description)/urdf/rplidar.urdf.xacro" />
```

and I run

```
rosrun xacro xacro --inorder diff_wheeled_robot.urdf.xacro
```

I get an error:

```
No such file or directory:  None None
when processing file: diff_wheeled_robot.urdf.xacro
```

What am I doing wrong?

ROS Kinetic

Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304511/xacro-include-breaks-including-xacro-file/) by [Julian98](https://answers.ros.org/users/33845/julian98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> <xacro:include filename="${find testbot_description)/urdf/rplidar.urdf.xacro" />
> ```

It should be `$(find ..)`, not `${find ..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julian98](https://answers.ros.org/users/33845/julian98/) on 2018-09-30**:
Thank you ;)